# Replicating IP based Apache settings locally

Tags: apache-2.2

I have 2 machines.

Machine A is remote development server running, Ubuntu, Apache, PostGres, [Custom Java Application + Tomcat]

Machine B is local development server, running as VM. I have managed to copy the database and Java App. And every thing is working good so far.

Now I want to replicate the apache settings aswell. Here is where I am having issues. I am not really versed in apache maintenance so I am looking for pointers.

Machine A, has 3 IP based virtual hosts.

```
1.2.3.4 pointing to var/www/a1
1.2.3.5 pointing to var/www/a2
1.2.3.6 pointing to var/www/a3
```

As mentioned I am trying to do this locally in my network, so my server B IP is 192.168.0.x

How do I set it up so that I can access these websites locally? I tried to assign "free" IP addresses to websites but its not working. By free IPs I mean random guesses I know which arent being used in my local network........ I guess I just dont know where to go from here. There are also SSL certificates I need to install aswell.....I would need to read up on that after I get the initial apache working....so..Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to assign "free" IP addresses to websites but its not working.

IP addresses are associated with interfaces not 'websites'.
You should set IP aliases on your B server interface, for instance:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.0.3 netmask 255.255.255.255 up
sudo ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.4 netmask 255.255.255.255 up
sudo ifconfig eth0:2 192.168.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.255 up
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I just stumbled upon this article which mentioned exactly that. I am going through it currently.  http://www.debianadmin.com/creating-name-based-and-ip-based-virtual-hosts-in-apache.html